# Create database if it doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a strange problem here; as I searched through the internet, including StackOverflow, the best, simpliest and fastest way to create data base only when such does not exists is using the following SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DataBase1
```

However, when I parse this statement in my C# code I get this error:

*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. Incorrect syntax near 'DataBase1'.*

The same happens when I try to execute the query in SSMS; I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'DataBase1'.
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your related application code

Comment: What version of MySql ? No idea when that feature was added ...

Comment: @Rahul the same happened with the SSMS, so this should be a syntax error from his MySql, no ?

Comment: @AxelH, why are executing that query in SSMS? I don't see any issue with the query though

Comment: @Rahul, why, to test it ? I don't either, but this could be an old MySql...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your code but your sql statement should looks like

```
string sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `DataBase1`;";
```

Comment: It looks like this:
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '" + dataBaseName + "';", connection);